# "For all our safety" instead of "for the safety of all", "for everyone's safety"

Tags: expressions

In the sentence: "It is vital that retailers, businesses and residents abide by these new measures which are being put in place **for all our safety**."  From [this](https://www.trafford.gov.uk/residents/news/articles/2020/20200325-Council-looks-to-ensure-businesses-close-to-stop-spread-of-coronavirus.aspx) source.

Does "for all our safety" here means "for the safety of all"? Or "for being 100 % safe"? Is that the most natural construction for expressing this idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ***for all our safety*** is syntactically valid. Nor do [most other people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20all%20our%20safety%2Cfor%20the%20safety%20of%20all&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20safety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20safety%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20safety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20safety%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0), apparently...

[image]

I think the problem here is that ***safety*** is an uncountable abstract noun, but the syntax of the context expects a pluralised noun - where *for all our X's* = *for all the X's that we have* (often, but not always, ***that we each have one or more of***). Hence [the six most common words](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20all%20our%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20sakes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20sins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20citizens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20wants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20needs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20purposes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20ills%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20actions%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20sakes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20sins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20citizens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20wants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20needs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20purposes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20ills%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20all%20our%20actions%3B%2Cc0) to follow *for all our...* are ***sakes, sins, needs, people, citizens, children***.

---

Here's another chart to prove the point. Note that the "invalid" versions (whether they try to explicitly pluralise *for all our **benefits*** or not, which would obviously be ridiculous with ***safeties***) do at least occur often enough to show at the bottom of the chart. I think this reflects the fact that there is some "tension" here - many people would *like* to be able to extend the usage, but it just doesn't quite work...

[image]

Comment: It's a colloquial construction that isn't so rare to hear, but is unlikely to make it through an editing pass of a book. Since news articles go through less and less editing these days, I'm unsurprised to see it show up in one.

Comment: I don't think "a colloquial construction" is justified here. Granted, *some* people have *sometimes* used it. But I suggest far more people would not only avoid using it themselves - they'd be in no doubt that anyone who *did* use the construction was making some kind of "mistake". So far as I'm concerned, people who fail to pluralise [*for all our **sakes***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+all+our+sake%2Cfor+all+our+sakes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20all%20our%20sakes%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...simply don't know English very well.

Comment: It depends if you consider one shared safety/sake or multiple individual ones. UK [police](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-56683745), councils, and [Parliament](https://www.parliament.uk/globalassets/documents/lords-committees/house-of-lords-commission/2017-19/UK_Parliament_Gender_Sensitive_Report_Response_Combined.pdf) seem to use "for all our safety" a lot. [Columbia Journalism Review](https://www.cjr.org/covering_climate_now/cop26_climate_summit.php) and writer [Erwin James](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-12879042) are 2 of many examples of "for all our sake".

Comment: Note that "all" is modifying "our", not "safety", so the singularity/plurality of "safety" does not matter. Likewise you could say "for all the soldiers' safety".

Comment: @StuartF: It wasn't that uncommon 2 centuries ago, but I think plural [*for all their **safeties***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+their+safeties%2Call+their+safety&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) is idiomatically unacceptable today (well - it is to *me*, at least).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted you to counterbalance the downvote! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!